# "Use of undeclared identifier"

Tags: ios, objective-c, properties, nsstring, uitextfield

I'm pretty new to Objective C. Keep getting this error

```
"Use of undeclared identifier"
```

for this line of code:

```
NSString *textOut1 = textOut.text;
```

Obviously I am just trying to pull the textbox text. I have declared the following in my h file

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *textOut;
```

So I cannot understand why I keep getting that damn error. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use this:

```
NSString *textOut1 = _textOut.text;
```

Checkout the extra underscore I added in front of `textOut`

Read the paragraph titled **Most Properties Are Backed by Instance Variables** in [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/EncapsulatingData/EncapsulatingData.html) apple documentation page.

Comment: This is true but it is best practice to use the property if there is one. So it would be better to use `self.textOut.text`.

Comment: @rmaddy: I agree with you. But actually I was focusing on the part of the question "**So I cannot understand why I keep getting that damn error**" and was suggesting that he was getting error because he missed an underscore

Comment: Or you could say he got the error because he forget the `self.`. :)

Answer (score 3):

To access the property `textOut` of an object referred to by the variable `someVariable`, you write `someVariable.textOut`. So to access the property `textOut` of the object that is `self`, you write `self.textOut`. You omitted the owner — `self` in this case.

Comment: Thanks Chuck, I understand much better now, however I am now getting a "use of undeclared identifier" error for line "NSString *textOut1 = self.textOut.textLayout;"

Comment: @Telexx: Does UITextField have a textLayout property? I don't think it does.

Comment: @Telexx: What is the identifier it says is undeclared?

Comment: @Telexx: Can you update the question with the context for the line (i.e. the method it's contained in)?

Answer (score 2):

If you are not  (@synthesize)  synthezising the property yourself then it will be  synthesized  with the instance variable having a Underscore at the start of the name.

try :

```
NSString *textOut1 = _textOut.text;
```

Comment: This is true but it is best practice to use the property if there is one. So it would be better to use `self.textOut.text`.

Comment: No, the *instance variable* will have an underscore. The property will not be prefixed.

Comment: Cheers. It is what I meant

Answer (score 2):

`self.textOut.text` is what you need.

A property is basically something like a class variable in Java that requires a public getter and setter to work with. So you cannot use it in a .m file directly, but need to utilize the getter and setter. Objective C on iOS actually provides you with these methods by itself. Hence, when you create a property, under the hood, you have code that does a getter and setter by itself.

You can set the value as :

```
_textOut = BLAHBLAH
```

And get it as :

```
[self textOut.text]
```

or
    `self.textOut.text`

or even `_textOut.text` (this is technically the local variable that is referenced by `textOut`)

Or in your case,

```
`NSString *textOut1 = [self textOut.text];`
```

or  `NSString *textOut1 = self.textOut.text;`

or  `NSString *textOut1 = _textOut.text;` // This is probably the least recommended one.

Though I believe the Stanford class says it is always better to do `[self textOut]`.